# Minimum of a Function in a given Interval

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, optimization, expected-value

So I wanted to proofs Bernsteins' Inequality for random variables and everything went well, but one thing. I need to show that the function:

$\mathrm{e}^{\frac{s^2v}{2(1-sB)} -st}, s \in [0,\frac{1}{B})$

is minimal for $s=\frac{t}{v+tB}$. I have problems showing that and I hope someone could help me on this.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I differentiated cause the function is continuous at least on the given interval but the result is nowhere near the intended solution. I only looked at the exponent because the exp is increasing and so i want to find a min for the exponent.

Comment: Ok, sounds good. I wrote down the solutions and checked with a symbolic solver, indeed it doesn't look like the expected answer. Maybe there's a typo in the function?

Comment: no theres no typo in it